# Why didn't Higuchi suspect that Rem killed Ginzo Kaneboshi as Rem wrote Ginzo's name in Higuchi's note book only?

Tags: death-note

When Rem killed Ginzo Kaneboshi, he wrote his name in the notebook that belonged to Higuchi. There's a possibility that Higuchi could check in the notebook that Ginzo's name was written there. Then why Higuchi didn't suspect Rem?

Answer (score 1):

Rem did not kill Ginzo Kaneboshi using Higuchis notebook. She wrote his name in Rems own personal notebook, which is later recovered by Light after her death.